# android - textview not centering

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio-2.2

The text view in my XML document does not center, need help with centering. What could i be doing wrong? I have added both android:gravity"center" and android:gravity"centerhorizontal" for testing but neither of them work.

UPDATE**  Fixed the problem by manually inserting a textview to center it, not ideal but it works.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_test"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eWelcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eTable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eWelcome"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/eWelcome"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#FF4081"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/eAttendance"
    android:layout_below="@id/eTable"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eAttendance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="207dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/eWelcome"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FF4081"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/eAttendance"
    android:layout_below="@id/eAttendance"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/textCaption" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a RelativeLayout as the root layout, this should do the trick:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your parent layout not RelativeLayout you should use layout_gravity. In your case, just add:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```